# Aparecer menu com o ng-click + ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou tentando fazer um menu lateral que apareça quando o usuário clique em um botão, usando uma classe .is-visible

```
<button ng-click="visible=!visible;">Click me to open the menu!</button>
<div ng-class="{'is-visible':visible}" class="menu">
 <a>Menu</a>
</div>
```

Ela funciona porém o efeito é aplicado somente na div, os elementos dentro da div (no caso o Menu não sofrem alteração, alguém pode me dar uma luz como aplicar o mesmo efeito em tudo que está dentro da div? Caso não esteja claro deixo o codepen abaixo com o que fiz:

http://codepen.io/haykou/pen/ichzI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta incluir `overflow: hidden` no seu menu. Ele inicialmente têm largura zero, mas o conteúdo vaza e fica sempre visível. Sua classe `menu` ficaria assim então:

```
.menu{
  width:0px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

<sup>http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kgKeG</sup>